# Math.random() not being recognized

Tags: java, math

Why is my code giving me a compile error saying that it can not find `random()`?

```
public class Math {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int randnum;
        randnum = (int)(Math.random() * 15);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println(randnum);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Name ambiguity? Your own class is called `Math`. Also, always add the exact error to your question.

Comment: Never, ever, name a custom type the same as a (well-known) type in the standard Java API. Type name collisions generally are resolved through fully-qualified names, as you easily could have known from the documentation. Also, your infinite loop would `println` the same output forever.

Answer (score 2):

You named your class `Math`, which shadows `java.lang.Math`. *Your* `Math` class has no `random()` method, hence the error. Pick a different name for your class to resolve the issue.

Comment: Or use fully-qualified type names.

Answer (score 1):

Either call the function as

`randnum = (int)(java.lang.Math.random() * 15);`

or rename your class to something else, not `Math`- it hides the inbuilt java package.

Answer (score 1):

Change the name of your own class `Math` to some other name, You class name conflict with `java.lang.Math` class name :

```
public class XYZ {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int randnum;

        randnum=(int) (Math.random()*15);
        while (true){
            System.out.println(randnum);
        }
    }
}
```

or you should use `randnum = (int)(java.lang.Math.random() * 15);`